# Make multiple plots with function call in loop in R

Tags: r, plot, quantmod

I'm trying to make multiple plots with the following code. (`da.list` is a list of xts objects, and `chart_Series` is a plotting function from the `quantmod` package.)

```
library(quantmod)

plotLoan = function(loanID){
  chart_Series( da.list[[loanID]], name = paste0('Loan ID: ', loanID))
}

LoanIDs = sample(names(da.list),6)
for (LoanID in LoanIDs) plotLoan(LoanID)
```

I'm not getting any output. However, `plotLoan(LoanIDs[1])` produces a plot as expected. Why won't this work in a loop?

Comment: Can you add parts of the data so that you have a MWE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the layout command? Not sure exactly what's going on but I expect it has something to do with not having enough room in the graphics device. You can try

```
layout(matrix(seq(6), nrow=3, ncol=2))
layout.show(6)
```

which will partition the graphics output and show where the next 6 plots will go. If you want to produce a different number of plots you will have to choose the dimensions based on your needs.